# value cannot be set in expected object format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am using react-select and redux form for autocomplete. There is a field called `listings_of` which is an array of data i need to post to the server. For this I used FieldArray concept. The data i get is not in value and label format which react-select expects so I have to use `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` props. For this i did the following way

```
const renderListingsOf = ({
  fields,
  data,
  meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }
}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
          Add Member
        </button>
      </li>
      {fields.map((listing, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <button
            type="button"
            title="Remove Member"
            onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
          />
          <Field
            name={`${listing}`}
            component={InputTextWithSearch}
            placeholder="Search..."
            options={(data && data.users.data) || []}
            getOptionLabel={option =>
              !isEmptyObject(option) && option.personal.first_name
            }
            getOptionValue={option => {
              if(!isEmptyObject(option)) {
                return {
                  _id       : option._id,
                  first_name: option.personal.first_name,
                  last_name : option.personal.last_name
                };
              }
            }}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};


<Column>
  <Query
    query={GET_USERS}
    variables={{
      param: {
        limit: 10
      }
    }}
  >
    {({ loading, data }) => {
      if(loading)return 'loading...';
      return (
        <InputFieldWrapper styling={styling} label="Listings of">
          <FieldArray
            name="general.general_information.listings_of"
            component={renderListingsOf}
            data={data}
          />
        </InputFieldWrapper>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
</Column>
```

data.users.data has the following object

```
[
  {
    _id: 'sdfskfjsdkjfsd',
    personal: {
      first_name: 'hello',
      last_name: 'hy'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 'sdjfkjfdkjskfdjkfff',
    personal: {
      first_name: 'hello1',
      last_name: 'hy1'
    }
  },
]
```

but when submitting the value for general.general_information.listings_of should be an array of object as below

```
general: {
  general_information: {
  listings_of: [
      {
        _id: 'sdfskfjsdkjfsd',
        first_name: 'hello',
        last_name: 'hy'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

thus i tried to return the following object from getOptionValue but its not working its like this

```
general: {
  general_information: {
  listings_of: [
      {
        _id: 'sdfskfjsdkjfsd',
        personal: {
          first_name: 'hello',
          last_name: 'hy'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry just to be sure to understand fine. The issue is that `first_name` and `last_name` are wrapped by another `personal` property?

Comment: you should abstract your UI away from your data structure.  your `options` could just be an array of the `_id`s that is transformed with `.map()` when rendering the UI.  when submitting you would use the `_id` to reference the original/full object with whatever format you need.

Comment: yes. The expected object when submitting is listings_of be {_id, first_name, last_name} not {_id, personal: {first_name, last_name}}

Comment: i am sorry I did not understand you @Deryck.

Comment: normalize the options array to fit what you expect (_id, first, last) - use the same code you use in the `getOptionValue()` prop but use it before passing the options at all as a prop value - so change `options={(data && data.users.data) || []}` to `options={((data && data.users.data) || []).map(opt => ({ _id: opt._id, first_name: opt.personal.first_name, last_name: opt.personal.last_name }) )}`

Comment: yes this one worked for me. Thanks a lot.